# Drools RuleRuntimeEventListener's objectUpdated method has same value for getObject and getOldObject methods

Tags: drools

I am using Drools version 6.5.0.Final and I have a simple rule like:

```
rule "Test Rule"
when
    $obj : MyObject(testValue == null || testValue != "NEW")
then
    $obj.testValue = "NEW";
    update($obj);
end
```

So I also implemented a RuleRuntimeEventListener class and it gets invoked when this rule is executed.  The problem is the passed in ObjectUpdatedEvent instance's getObject() and getOldObject() calls return the same exact object - which is the object after the update.  So for this the getOldObject() call returns an object that has a value of "NEW" for the testValue property.  I am expecting getOldObject to return me the value of testValue that isn't "NEW" which is after it was changed by the rule.

This seems like a bug to me and was wondering if anybody had any similar issues with this or if there is any workaround?  I want to be notified when any property of an object is changed by a rule and what the old and new values were.

I see that there is support for using the java bean's PropertyChangeListener, but that looks like I have to create the fact objects with a addPropertyChangeListener and removePropertyChangeListener methods and also in all my fact's setter methods I have to use PropertyChangeSupport and fire a property change event via firePropertyChange method.  I really don't want to have to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you investigated all possibilities provided by event listeners reacting to before and after rule fired? There would be the possibility of preserving the old state of participating objects, something you can't expect to happen by default as it would severely punish all apps that don't need that. - Auditing changes can also be implemented in additional RHS code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I think I have investigated everything and I don't see what I could possibly be missing in order for that event listener to pass me the object before and after the update.  I don't see what the point of having the getOldObject() method if its not passing me the before values.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Drools, the issue is also present in 7.16.0.FINAL. By doing the following

```
System.out.println(getOldObject() == getObject());
```

You will get an output of "true" indicating that both objects are of the same reference.

I just raised it as a bug on the Drools site

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-4305

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Differ implements AgendaEventListener {

     private List<Object> oldFacts;

     public void beforeMatchFired(BeforeMatchFiredEvent event){
         List<Object> facts = event.getMatch().getObjects();
         // copy (!) facts into oldFacts
     }

     public void afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent event){
         List<Object> facts = event.getMatch().getObjects();
         // compare facts with oldFacts
     }
     //...
}
```

You may want to be more selective in copying and comparing. Also, a generic way of comparing using the stringified object contents might be considered.

```
  BeforeMatchFiredEvent
```

Comment: Thanks, so with this solution however I would be copying the old fact objects even though I wouldn't know yet if the old fact objects will even be modified by the rule.  Also would I not use the objectUpdated(ObjectUpdatedEvent event) method in RuleRuntimeEventListener at all?  If so then what is the point of this method?  Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the rule you do know which facts are changed - that's why I wrote ("be more selective"). -- What is the point of trying to keep track - in full detail - of all changes anyway? Or not integrating this in the rule's RHS where you know what is being changed? - As I've indicated previously, a generic solution is bound to cause some overhead.